# How to fix session not created Exception on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I have automation test scripts which is running based on web drivers (Firefox, chrome, Edge) on my windows laptop but in Jenkins build has failed due to below error and Jenkins running based on Linux os.

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find msedge binary 
Host info: host: 'ip-10-1-1-111', ip: '10.1.1.111'
Build info: version: '4.12.1', revision: '8e34639b11'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.19.0-1025-aws', java.version: '11.0.20.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
```

I have integrated Jenkins from GitHub. When I push the automation code (Java-Selenium) the build job gets triggered. Where all the dependencies are downloaded on Jenkins console but build failed due to session not created exception displayed.

I am expecting to get the successful build because **same code executed successfully on my local machine (windows 11**). In my project I am used
1.selenium plugin 4.12.1
2.TestNG 7.4.0
3.Webdrivermanager plugin 5.3.3

**Jenkins console output:**

```
`[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running TestSuite
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 3.562 s <<< FAILURE! -- in TestSuite
[ERROR] org.testpackage.TC001_Signup.launch[org.testng.TestRunner@4b3fe06e, chrome](0) -- Time elapsed: 2.989 s <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
Host info: host: 'ip-10-1-1-111', ip: '10.1.1.111'
Build info: version: '4.12.1', revision: '8e34639b11'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.19.0-1025-aws', java.version: '11.0.20.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*], binary: /opt/google/chrome/google-c..., extensions: []}}]}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:140)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:96)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:196)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:602)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:72)
    at org.basepackage.VisionBaseClass.launch(VisionBaseClass.java:142)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:700)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:527)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:308)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:71)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:113)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495)

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:

(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
Host info: host: 'ip-10-1-1-111', ip: '10.1.1.111'
Build info: version: '4.12.1', revision: '8e34639b11'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.19.0-1025-aws', java.version: '11.0.20.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*], binary: /opt/google/chrome/google-c..., extensions: []}}]}]
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2`
```